# Pros and cons of list views vs dynamic view creation list view

Tags: android, android-listview

I know that android `ListView` handles *row reuse* whereas *dynamic `View` creation* of a list view doesn't, but are there any other pros to using a `ListView` versus ?

Comment: I think you're confused. Row reusing and dynamic view creation are used together to implement listviews.

Comment: hmn.. maybe I phrased this poorly. What I was trying to get at Is dynamic views created in code not via list view's getView but aggregated into a list view format.

Comment: @cj1098 what dynamic view creation do you mean?

Comment: For example: inflating a relative layout with a textview and imageview every time a button Is pressed. If you were using Android 's listView to increase your list size you'd Just increment your arraylist or data.size () and then notify the adapter. I'm talking about neither using an adapter or a listView (). Creating each row dynamically. I know the garbage collector that comes with the listView () is really nice and the way it reuses off - screen rows is great but what other advantages/disadvantages are there for doing it without listViews help?

Comment: i see , but is that just an academic question or you have some specific issue/problem you dont know how to solve?

Comment: Purely academic question sir! I'd like to know :)

Comment: Listviews are great when your data length is not known but when you have fixed data with up to dozen items i woyld use dynamic view creation placed in a linear layout and a scrollview